# How to write comma-separated values in a CSV file in python?

Tags: python, file, csv

```
with open('value.csv', 'w') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)


while time < stage1_burn_time:
# Calculate update simulation variables based on current values:
altitude = altitude + (velocity * delta_t)
acceleration = (thrust(altitude, stage1_thrust_sl, stage1_thrust_vac) / mass) - gravity
velocity = velocity + (acceleration * delta_t)
mass = mass - burn_rate * delta_t
time = time + delta_t
writer.writerow(velocity')
writer.writerow('altitude')
writer.writerow('mass')
```

This is part of the code, what I want to do is to record the values as a line of comma-separated values in a CSV file, and I got a error message Error: iterable expected, not float

Answer (score 1):

```py
import csv

with open('values.csv', mode='w') as values_file:
    values_writer = csv.writer(values_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    values_writer.writerow(['velocity1', 'Altitude1', 'Mass1'])
    values_writer.writerow(['velocity2', 'Altitude2', 'Mass2'])
```

Reference: https://realpython.com/python-csv/